# Save all POST data to database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert

I register in a software gateway, for each sale it send many data using IPN to my server, and
I want to save all of them in database. Is there any quick way to save all POST data in a database without using SQL?

Comment: Nope. (Min chars limit sucks)

Comment: use some frameworks components https://github.com/symfony/Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [SafeMysql abstraction library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) you need to list your fields only once

```
$allowed = array('title','url','body','rating','term','type');
$data = $db->filterArray($_POST,$allowed);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ?n SET ?u";
$db->query($sql,$table,$data);
```

Comment: Glad you liked it. It was my aim - to make everyday tasks easy yet perfectly safe

Answer (score 6):

Well... its an odd way to be doing things for sure. But if you simply want to store "all post data" you might aswell use `serialize($_POST);`  and store that in your database ( in a TEXT column).

When you read it from the database, use `unserialize()` to turn the data back into the original array.

I wouldn't recommend doing such a thing, but its what you asked.

Comment: Yeah. - vote a correct answer on a silly question why dont you... Especially the lack of comment is very gentlemen-like. If you don't like the idea, - vote the question, not the answers.

Comment: I did it for you dude :)

Comment: Damien- You are right (thumbup)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = serialize ($_POST)
```

Now you can store str in your database and when you need your values back just deserialize it again.

Comment: + voting to compensate for the troll that -voted. Do the same :)

Comment: @Varun Bajaj thanks,,,,,why some people give me -vote?!!?

Comment: I don;t know the reason for others but yes i did -vote for lack of comments or verbage of question, which leads to the answer suggested by me that was not sought by you!